# Retrieve list of buckets from all regions using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I was trying to retrieve the list of buckets from all regions using boto3, however I am unable to list the buckets from the correct region

So far I have tried `location['LocationConstraint']`, which comes up as `None`
I have also tried the following as well but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

```
if client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-bucket-region'] == 'us-east-1':
                print ("bucketname %s " % s3_bucket.name)
```

**Code**

```
import json
import boto3

bucketlist = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get list of regions
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )

    # Iterate over regions
    for region in regions:
    
        print ("*************** Checking region  --   %s " % region['RegionName'])
        reg=region['RegionName']
    
        client = boto3.client('s3', region_name=reg)

        response = client.list_buckets()
        for bucket in response['Buckets']:
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=reg)
            s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket['Name'])
            if client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-bucket-region'] == 'us-east-1':
                print ("bucketname %s " % s3_bucket.name)
                bucketlist.append(s3_bucket)
    return {
        "statusCode": 200
    }
```

**Output:** The buckets `testbucket1` and `testbucket2` are only available in `us-east-1` region

```
START RequestId: e22f6ac0-7bb9-4e2b-84d7-5512ce97acfa Version: $LATEST
*************** Checking region  --   eu-north-1 
bucketname testbucket1 
bucketname testbucket2 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-south-1 
bucketname testbucket1 
bucketname testbucket2 
[...]
*************** Checking region  --   us-east-1 
bucketname testbucket1
bucketname testbucket2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
START RequestId: e22f6ac0-7bb9-4e2b-84d7-5512ce97acfa Version: $LATEST
*************** Checking region  --   eu-north-1 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-south-1 
*************** Checking region  --   eu-west-3 
*************** Checking region  --   eu-west-2 
*************** Checking region  --   eu-west-1 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-northeast-3 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-northeast-2 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-northeast-1 
*************** Checking region  --   sa-east-1 
*************** Checking region  --   ca-central-1 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-southeast-1 
*************** Checking region  --   ap-southeast-2 
*************** Checking region  --   eu-central-1 
*************** Checking region  --   us-east-1 
bucketname testbucket1 
bucketname testbucket2 
*************** Checking region  --   us-east-2 
*************** Checking region  --   us-west-1 
*************** Checking region  --   us-west-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change region for client. `list_buckets` returns **all buckets** in the account, regardless where they are located. That's why you get the same buckets for each region in your code.

You have to iterate over `list_buckets` results, and use [get_bucket_location](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_location) to obtain the actual locations of your buckets. For example:

```
all_buckets = client.list_buckets()

for bucket in all_buckets['Buckets']:
  bucket_bame = bucket["Name"]
  region = client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_bame)["LocationConstraint"]
  print(bucket_bame, region)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @marcin. I also noticed another issue. The region seems to be coming up as `None`. However for another person, he was able to get the region with his account

`testbucket1 None`
`testbucket2 None`

Comment: @kasukur Then default region is the used. Us-east-1.